# How to import a sheet from another Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Scipt?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to import a sheet from another Google Spreadsheet in place of values only using Google Apps Script, and check if the existing sheet is there or not. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
  function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AjN7uZG....'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Monthly'); // ss = source sheet
  //Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  //get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  //get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('8AjN7u....'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('RAWData'); // ts = target sheet
  //set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/* Global configuration */
const CONFIG = {
  URL: {
    /* Enter the source sheet url between '' */
    SOUCE_SHEET_URL: '',
  },
  SHEET_TO_COPY: {
    /* Enter the source sheet name between '' */
    SHEET_NAME: '',
  },
  SPREADSHEET: {
    ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
  },
  TOAST: {
    T1: 'Sheet found, deleting the current version.',
    T2: 'Sheet not found, copying the new sheet.',
    T3: 'Sheet copied successfully.',
    T4: 'Enter the correct url and sheet name.',
  }
};

const importSheet = () => {
  try {
    const sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(CONFIG.URL.SOUCE_SHEET_URL).getSheetByName(CONFIG.SHEET_TO_COPY.SHEET_NAME);
    /* Before copying the sheet, delete the exiting copy (if any) */
    const existingSheet = CONFIG.SPREADSHEET.ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET.getSheetByName(CONFIG.SHEET_TO_COPY.SHEET_NAME);
    if (existingSheet) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(CONFIG.TOAST.T1, 'Status', 3);
      Utilities.sleep(2000);
      CONFIG.SPREADSHEET.ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET.deleteSheet(existingSheet);
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(CONFIG.TOAST.T2, 'Status', 3);
      Utilities.sleep(2000);
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    const destinationSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(CONFIG.SPREADSHEET.ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET);
    destinationSheet.setName(CONFIG.SHEET_TO_COPY.SHEET_NAME);
    CONFIG.SPREADSHEET.ACTIVE_SPREADSHEET.setActiveSheet(destinationSheet);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(CONFIG.TOAST.T3, 'Success ', 3);
  }
  catch (err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(CONFIG.TOAST.T4, 'Failed ', 3);
  }
};
```